# Querying nested arrays of hashes in Postgres JSON datatype?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So I've read through the Postgres JSON querying examples and I'm pretty sure there's no way to query our data as structured, but I wanted to make absolutely sure as it will require multiple changes to our code base :)

We are currently storing the following data in a serialized text field in Postgres. We would like to be able to query against the values, which are either `nil` or arrays-of-hashes `[{a : 1, b: 2},{c: 3, d: 4}]` to see if the hash values themselves contain a hash witch has a certain value (in the example below `facebook` or `102`).

```
{  "statuses": nil,
   "services_and_accounts": [
        {
          "id": "facebook",
          "enabled": false
        },
        {
           "id": 102,
           "enabled": false
        }
      ]
}
```

Is this possible in pure SQL using the JSON datatype?